# If a 'distance function' does not possess triangle inequality property, would the limit of a converging sequence still be unique?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a set and $d$ be a function such that $d:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that it satisfies positivity, that is, $d(x,y)\geq 0$ and $d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y.$ Moreover suppose it satisfies symmetry property, that is, $d(x,y)=d(y,x).$ However it does not satisfy triangle inequality.

Obviously if triangle inequality was to be satisfied then this will make $(X,d)$ a metric space and subsequently every converging sequence will have a unique limit. Hence I am just curious if this property is taken away, can there still be examples such that every converging sequence has a unique limit with respect to this function $d$?

I hope I explained my question sufficiently clear, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really mean something like "can there be at least one sequence in $X$ having two or more limit points"?

Comment: Well the standard proof of the uniqueness of limits in a metric space is entirely dependent on the triangle inequality, so my guess would be that limits aren't unique in this case. However I can't think of an example off the top of my head.

Comment: Yes, just take a true distance $D(x,y)$ and any increasing function $f$ with $f(0)=0$ and define $d(x,y) = f(D(x,y))$. For example $D(x,y)^2$. It will not verify triangle inequality but every limit will be unique.

Comment: @coffeemath No I dont quite mean limit points but rather non-uniqueness in its limits (I think they are different things?) (s.harp's answer is exactly what i was looking for!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d(x,y) = (x-y)^2$ on $\Bbb R$, which satisfies the first two axioms but not the triangle inequality, because:
$$d(0,2)=4\not≤2=d(0,1)+d(1,2)$$
however limits are still unique, in fact you have the same limits as the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, since $(x_n-y)^2\to0$ iff $|x_n-y|\to0$ (continuity of the root on positive numbers).

There exist "metrics" failing the triangle inequality without unique limits:

Let $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0 & x=y \\ \frac1{|xy|}
&x\neq y\end{cases}$$
on $\Bbb N$, then you have that any unbounded sequence $x_n$ converges to any integer.

Comment: I wonder then what the necessary and sufficient conditions are for limits to be unique?

Comment: A sufficient and extremely sensible condition is that the map $d: X\times X \to\Bbb R$ is _continuous_ wrt the notion of convergence given by $x_\alpha \to x\iff d(x_\alpha, x)\to0$, or at least sectionally continuous meaning $x\mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous for some or all $y$. For a normal metric this is guaranteed by the triangle inequality. To find an iff condition doesn't seem so useful to me.